# Min value per row, Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need the min distance per member (ID). My input is like this:

```
ID      ColA        DistA   DistB   DistC   DistD
1001    SomeValueA  11.08   12.07   9.89    19.77
1002    SomeValueB  16.04   55.78   17.55   3.55
1003    SomeValueC  12.09   16.78   5.44    27.44
```

Expected result would be:

```
ID      ColA        MinDistance
1001    SomeValueA  9.89
1002    SomeValueB  3.55
1003    SomeValueC  5.44
```

I'm thinking about groupby, but this works in the wrong direction. I need aggregate on a row basis.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards, M.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for get only column with `Dist` with `min` function:

```
df['MinDistance'] = df.filter(like='Dist').min(axis=1)
```

Or if possible select columns by positions use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['MinDistance'] = df.iloc[:, 2:].min(axis=1)
```

Comment: In one line.  :) Should have learned python instead of SQL.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @SQL_M - Each of this languages is better for something else ;)